# Given an array of integers, remove the n smallest - Codewars, Python

Tags: python, arrays

[Here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/563ce9b8b91d25a5750000b6/python) is the link for Codewars page.

My code fails the tests part of the question given below,
Q: Given an array of integers, remove the `n` smallest. If there are multiple elements with the same value, remove the ones with a lower index first. If n is greater than the length of the array/list, return an empty list/array. If `n` is zero or less, return the original array/list.
Don't change the order of the elements that are left.

And here is my attempt:

```
def remove_smallest(n, arr):
    if n > 0:
        smallest_nums = sorted(arr)[:n]
        return [x for x in arr if x not in smallest_nums]
    return arr
```

I am not able to figure out the reason why my code does not work, it manages to pass all the basic 7 tests when I test the code, but when I try to attempt, my code fails quite a few of the random tests. The arrays used in the random tests are very huge, and I am not sure how to use them to find out where I went wrong. Any sort of advice that will help me debug the code by providing some techniques will be really helpful, Thank you.

Comment: reading your code, I dont see how you treat duplicates of the same value. what does  remove_smallest(1, [8,9,8]) gives you ?

Comment: oh now I get it, my function returns [9], but actually it should return [9, 8]. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `return` statement takes values that are not in that `smallest_nums`, but that could be filtering away too much. Some occurrences of the maximum value in that `smallest_nums` might still need to stay in the list.

Here is a minimal input for which your code fails:

```
print(remove_smallest(1, [1, 1]))
```

This prints an empty list, but it should print `[1]`.

So you'll need to take into account how many of that maximum value are in the original input and how many you have put in the `smallest_nums` and leave the difference in `arr`.

If you need a spoiler, here is your code adapted with that fix:

> `def remove_smallest(n, arr):
>      if n > 0 and arr:
>          smallest_nums = sorted(arr)[:n]
>          greatest = smallest_nums[-1]
>          count = len(smallest_nums) - smallest_nums.index(greatest)
>          return [x for x in arr
>                  if x not in smallest_nums
>                  or (x == greatest and (count := count - 1) < 0)]
>      return arr`

Answer (score 1):

Of course there are many ways to do this. You could use list.remove() which gives concise code but not necessarily the most efficient:

```
def remove_smallest(n, arr):
    if n <= 0:
        return arr
    for x in sorted(ac := arr.copy())[:n]:
        ac.remove(x)
    return ac
```